# TFS. Apply pattern matching to a double field

Tags: tfs, pattern-matching

There are system fields:

[image: Effort]

As I understand these fields are of type double. TFS does not allow you to enter letters into these fields.

My problem is that TFS allows you to enter a dot (`.`) or a comma (`,`) in the fields. But if you enter a comma (`,`) in the field, TFS deletes it after saving the form. For example, the number `15,50` will be converted to `1550`.

I understand that this can be partially corrected by the Windows localization settings, but this option does not work. does not provide a 100% guarantee.

The documentation found that you can use pattern matching, but this only applies to fields of type string (https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/vsts/work/customize/reference/apply-pattern-matching-to-string-field).

How can I check the value in the field so that when I enter `15,50` I get `15.50` or an error when saving?

Used version of TFS `15.117.27024.0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the feature is not supported for now.

You can only set that with dot (`.`), but it will remove the `0` if the last bit is `0`, that means you can only get `15.5` but not `15.50`.

And there isn't a rule to match the condition which contains a comma (`,`) in the fields (See [Assign conditional-based values and rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/customize/reference/assign-conditional-based-values-and-rules)). So, we also cannot set error when saving.

Actually there's already a **[user voice here](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/31642753-allow-comma-as-decimal-character-when-entering-rem)** to suggest this feature, you can go and vote it up to help achieving that in future.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can I implement this using the [onFieldChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/extend/develop/add-workitem-extension) event?

Comment: @Kolya_Net No, I don't think you can achieve that with `onFieldChanged` event. Just see the Event description : `"Fired after a field has changed. If the field change ran rules which updated other fields, all these changes are part of a single event."` So, it's based on the rules, but unfortunately there isn't such a rule to match the condition as I mentioned in above answer.